# Modalverb und Satzstruktur

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context, modal-verb

Sind beide korrekt oder was stimmt nicht ?

> Ich muss mich beim Lesen der Hausnummer versehen haben.

Das sollte korrekt sein. Der nächste Satz klingt zweifelhafter für mich.

> Ich habe mich beim Lesen der Hausnummer versehen müssen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im [epistemischen Gebrauch](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1552) – also wenn es um das Wissen des Sprechers oder um [Evidentialität](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Evidentialit%C3%A4t) geht – haben die Modalverben keine Vergangenheitsformen. Daher haben Sätze wie der folgende keine epistemische Lesart:

> Meine Frau hat das Buch bestellen müssen.
> *nur:* Es war notwendig, dass meine Frau das Buch bestellt.
> *aber nicht:* Ich bin fast sicher, dass meine Frau das Buch bestellt hat.

Die Eigenschaft, keine Vergangenheitsformen zu haben, teilen die Modalverben im epistemischen Gebrauch mit dem sogenannten Futurhilfsverb *werden*. Das ist insofern nicht verblüffend, als dieses oft nicht zum Ausdruck von Zukünftigkeit, sondern zum Ausdruck von Vermutungen gebraucht wird.

> Er wird sich verletzt haben.
> ~ Ich vermute, dass er sich verletzt hat.

Wie das letzte Beispiel zeigt, kann *werden* sich mit einem Infinitiv Perfekt verbinden (was in der traditionellen Grammatik als *Futur II* bezeichnet wurde). Dasselbe gilt für die epistemisch gebrauchten Modalverben.

> Meine Frau muss das Buch bestellt haben.
> ~ Ich bin fast sicher, dass meine Frau das Buch bestellt hat.

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct, but they mean different things.

"Ich muss mich versehen haben" == "I guess I must have been mistaken."

"Ich habe mich versehen müssen." == "[Unfortunately] I was forced to make a mistake."

The latter meaning is somewhat obscure; to justify it you'd have to imagine e.g. someone being held at gunpoint and forced to falsify data for some nefarious reason.

Comment: Warum eine englische Antwort auf eine auf Deutsch gestellte Frage?

Answer (score -2):

Der zweite Satz ist falsch, du hast zwei unterschiedliche Zeitformen, Vergangenheit und Zukunft das geht nicht. Das müssen kannst du auch weglassen dann geht der Satz auch.

Comment: Das ist falsch, der zweite Satz ist richtig. Und da ist auch kein Futur drin.